# for-loop with async function runs out memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Before you start shouting "Do not use for-loops with async functions!" let me state that I **do** know how to program a loop with async functions calling the next iteration from within the callback.

But what, if I am not interested in the callback or in processing one iteration only if the predecessor has finished. In my case I am importing a big number of records from an xml-file and writing them into a mongoDB. The normal call to my "write"-function would be like this:

```
asyncWrite( record, function(err, result) {
    ...
});
```

Now as I said, im not interested in the callback (no errors will occur!) nor in a serial process. So I used a for-loop and left out the callback:

```
for( i=0; i<max; i+=1) {
    asyncWrite( record_arr[i] );
}
```

For small `max` this works perfectly. But with `max` getting bigger (> 100.000) I end up getting an 'out of memory' error. The only way to prevent this was turning back to a 'normal' async-loop (recursive function call from within the callback).

Any other idea?

Comment: you are calling the function as "asyncWrite( record_arr[i] )". where is the other parameter of the function?

Comment: Maybe try process.nextTick(function(){asyncWrite( record_arr[i] );});

Comment: @polin: I left it out by intention, because, as I said, I do not want to process anything within the callback.

Comment: @Chris: Will that help? I think that shifts the problem only one step in front. The filled-up-queue-problem will not vanish, won`t it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The async functions will not be executed until the for-loop has done its work. It has just collected a queue that is too beg. For big `max` you got `out of memory` error because the queue is full. You can see how your memory leaks by inserting `console.log(process.memoryUsage());` inside of the loop. You need to work with chunks to process this task.